# Share a YouTube Video URL to my App

Tags: android, android-intent, video-streaming, android-youtube-api

i am able to open a video on youtube app and make it open my app on pressing the share button but i want the video URL to be pasted in my Edit Text or simply copied to the clipboard, that would do the job

```
TextView uri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />              
 <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want, is it retrieving the video page on Youtube.com page, or the URL of the video feed ?

Comment: i want the video URL to be copied so that i can paste it on some youtube downloading website

Comment: It is not possible to retrieve the video feed URL by sharing it from the video feed app.

Comment: The Youtube app will only share the page of the video on Youtube.com. To retrieve the Youtube video feed, you need to use an unstable, undocumented API.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible!

Manifest (in one activity):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null) {
    String link = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("link", link);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

I hope it will help!